# Java Jar starts from command line , but not from intellij idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am able to start the server with the command line 'java -jar jarname.jar
But , while running main method of the spring boot application , server start fails ,saying that a class from an imported dependency project does not exists

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/jj/db/repositories/KKRepository;
```

Also there is a warning message in the console :

```
2021-11-15 11:04:47 WARN  WebappClassLoaderBase:173 -   - The web application [MM] appears to have started a thread named [RxIoScheduler-1 (Evictor)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215) java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Are you using Maven? If so, check if your dependencies are all included. Execute a Maven Build to make sure everything is working. Also, while youre in pom.xml IntelliJ should display a maven symbol on the top right after you added dependencies, make sure you've clicked it in order to install all dependencies.

Comment: using maven , and all things are done too. But still error

Comment: How are you trying to run the main method? Also, when you run `java -jar ...` Is it a single jar file, or do you have more jars that are specified in the manifest. It sounds like when you run your main class you're not using a classpath with all of the appropriate dependencies. Often this is a module classpath, and that module should have the appropriate dependencies attached.

Comment: there is an outer project ,which has modules specified in pom . The main project is one of the module.

Comment: How are you trying to run the main method?

Comment: Thanks Matt..I am able to start now in intellij...i made it as a single module project now

Comment: Nobody can debug invisible code. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on GitHub, in order not to waste your bounty points on bad or no answers.

Comment: matt was able to identify the issue with invisible code. i will accept his answer if he adds it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Instead of a multi-module project, make it as a single module project or specify appropriately in the manifest.*